# More complex AD distinguishedName parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

So, I have AD distinguishedName strings like the following (which is the value of acad.ADCn):

```
CN=Surname\, Firstname (something),OU=Subdepartment,OU=Department,OU=Fixed,OU=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed
```

The "Fixed" values are irrelevant and always the same, also it's always the same number of elements from the right. The Department and Subdepartment fields are the important thing here (and their names can be **anything**).

I wrote the following code to read the Subdepartment and return it as `S.<Subdepartmentname>`:

```
SELECT
    acad.ADCn
    , 'S.' + (
        SELECT
            RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value, 'CN=', ''), 'DC=', ''), 'OU=', '')))
        FROM (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT '')) AS rowid,
                value
            FROM
                STRING_SPLIT(acad.ADCn, ',')
            ORDER BY
                rowid DESC
            OFFSET 6 ROW
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
        ) AS splittable
    ) AS Subdepartment
    , acad.AccountName
    , acb.MailAddress
FROM
    MyDB.dbo.AccountAD AS acad
LEFT JOIN
    MyDB.dbo.AddressCB AS acb
    ON
        acad.ID
        = acb.ID
```

This works well if (and only if) the Subdepartment is the 7th element from the right. But this isn't always the case. There's also the case that some users are just within a Department and not within a Subdepartment, meaning that one element is missing. In that case, the query should return `D.<Departmentname>` instead of `S.<Subdepartmentname>`. And since this is a different level of nesting (you have to choose the 6th element from the right instead of the 7th) I find it hard to extend the code to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If it wasn't clear yet, here are two more examples:

```
CN=Surname\, Firstname (something),OU=Coolsubdepartmentname,OU=Departmentname,OU=Fixed,OU=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed
```

Should return: `S.Coolsubdepartmentname`

```
CN=Surname\, Firstname (something),OU=Onlydepartmentname,OU=Fixed,OU=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed
```

Should return: `D.Onlydepartmentname`

Also, there may or may not be an additional comma inside the `CN=` to the left, which is why I've always counted from the right side where the number of elements are fixed.

And the whole thing should still be inside the subquery of the outer SELECT (like in the example code) since I also need to select the other values (AccountName and MailAddress) from elsewhere.

Comment: If you have a long term need to solve this problem, you might want to consider using a full regex, possibly through a UDF.  A query using the base string functions is going to be tough.

Comment: Or maybe count the number of OUs and then have 2 different CASEs (i.e., double the code)? But that's also inconvenient.